# How to Calibrate a Model That has Points (Not Probabilities) as Variable?

Tags: r, validation, model, statistics

I'm working in an external validation project and I have some doubts regarding testing the calibration of a model. My project regards validation of Community Acquired Pneumonia Scores in a Retrospective Cohort, however, for this question, I will create a simulated data-set.

Suppose I have 3 predictor variables (hemoglobin, creatinine and sex) which are continuous, continuous and binary respectively and the outcome is death which is also binary outcome.

And suppose there is a model out there that says that points for hemoglobin, creatinine and sex to predict death. It assigns 1 point if male, 2 points if hemoglobin less or equal to 12 and 3 points if creatinine greater or equal to 1. I then calculate the respective score in R and will have the outcome in numbers from 0 to 6 maximum. I have the also the outcome of those patients, however, I have a scale in points and not probabilities. How can I test the calibration of this model?

The simplest way that comes to my mind is fitting it a logistic model (eg. glm(data = outcome, death ~ score)) and then using for example the function calibrate from rms package to plot it. However, I'm concerned that fitting a logistic regression model would 'train' and overfitt the model to my data (slope would be 1 and intercept 0). A second way of doing that would be going after the original paper where they validated the score and getting their predicted death rates by each level of score. However, I dont think people would actually do that.

Here goes the code.

To make things easier for understanding, my problem is validating the PSI (Pneumonia Severity Assessment) in a cohort of COVID-19 patients. However, my PSI score ranges from 1-5 only.

Thanks in advance.

````r
library(tidyverse)
library(rms)

df <- data.frame(id = 1:20, 
           hemoglobin = rnorm(20, mean = 13, sd = 2),
           creatinine = rnorm(20, mean = 0.8, sd = 0.2),
           sex = rbinom(20, 1, 0.5),
           death = rbinom(20, 1, 0.2))

df
#>    id hemoglobin creatinine sex death
#> 1   1  14.647678  0.9027220   0     0
#> 2   2  14.220308  1.0181192   0     1
#> 3   3  14.540249  0.7445206   1     0
#> 4   4  12.173647  0.6452908   0     0
#> 5   5  11.713601  0.8535807   0     0
#> 6   6   9.971964  0.4272673   0     1
#> 7   7  11.489067  0.6374971   0     1
#> 8   8  13.532228  0.7572170   1     0
#> 9   9  13.742081  0.6465518   0     0
#> 10 10  10.249797  0.4877277   1     1
#> 11 11  10.389741  0.6760747   0     1
#> 12 12  15.043165  0.7012690   0     0
#> 13 13  11.976079  1.1220017   1     0
#> 14 14  15.905599  1.1381758   1     0
#> 15 15  14.369145  1.0629459   1     0
#> 16 16  14.034443  0.7007272   1     0
#> 17 17  15.656715  0.6277480   1     1
#> 18 18   7.496555  0.8633633   1     1
#> 19 19  12.590283  0.6671725   1     0
#> 20 20  11.709377  0.9579166   1     0


df$score <- 1*(df$sex == 1) + 2*(df$hemoglobin <= 12) + 3*(df$creatinine >= 1)

df$score
#>  [1] 0 3 1 0 2 2 2 1 0 3 2 0 6 4 4 1 1 3 1 3

model <- glm(data = df, death ~ score, family = 'binomial')

df$prob <- predict(model, df, type = 'response')

val.prob(df$prob, df$death)
```

    #>           Dxy       C (ROC)            R2             D      D:Chi-sq 
    #>  3.186813e-01  6.593407e-01  3.340394e-02 -2.544734e-02  4.910532e-01 
    #>           D:p             U      U:Chi-sq           U:p             Q 
    #>            NA -1.000000e-01  3.552714e-15  1.000000e+00  7.455266e-02 
    #>         Brier     Intercept         Slope          Emax           E90 
    #>  2.236665e-01 -6.026885e-11  1.000000e+00  7.162773e-01  4.008586e-01 
    #>          Eavg           S:z           S:p 
    #>  2.505908e-01  5.303483e-02  9.577042e-01
```
````

Comment: You could compute its ROC and report the area under the curve (c statistic)

Comment: Hi Allan, Thanks for the answer. That’s feasible however I’m not interested in the ROC but the calibration itself.